# CakePHP 3.8 Blog Tutorial Error: Mising Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi I followed this tutorial: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html and having problem when tried to access the links: ***localhost/myprojectname/articles/index*** and ***localhost/myprojectname/articles/view/1***

This is the screenshot:
[Error:Missing Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjUpu.png)

I am using XAMPP and Chrome browser. The article model, articles controller and article view are created as written in the tutorial. But when I was trying to access the link at ***localhost/myprojectname/articles/index***, there is missing controller error as shown in the screenshot above.

However, after insert `<?php` in the top of the articles controller and article model file, still showing same missing controller error as this screenshot: [Error: Missing Controller 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spf0T.png)

Comment: Looks like the actual code of your Articles controller is presented as text above the error message. Presumably, somehow missing the `<?php` at the top of that file?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I just tried to insert the `<?php` in the top of articles controller and article model file. But still having same problem without the text shown above the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this to your AppController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('articles', $this->Articles->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('article'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. I had solved the problem before this. Actually the error was caused by an incorrect file path in my project folder. I was trying to link the articles' view file to the ArticlesController.php inside another folder instead of the Articles folder.It works.